# Derivation of indefinite integral involving hypergeometric function

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration, special-functions, hypergeometric-functions

I am doing a project on projectile motion and I ended up with this integral:

$$\int \frac{m \left(g - \left(\frac{1}{e^t - g^{\frac{m}{c}}}\right)^{\frac{m}{c}}\right)}{c} \, dt$$

where $g, c,$ and $m$ were constants.
Having no idea how to integrate this equation, I put it into Wolfram Alpha. Wolfram Alpha came out with this solution:

$$ \frac{m \left(g t - \frac{c g^{-\frac{m}{c}} \left(\frac{1}{e^t - g^{\frac{m}{c}}}\right)^{\frac{m}{c} - 1} \, _2F_1\left(1, 1 - \frac{m}{c}, 2 - \frac{m}{c}, 1 - e^t g^{-\frac{m}{c}} \right)}{c - m}\right)}{c} + \text{constant} $$

I cannot for the life of me figure out how Wolfram Alpha got this answer even after asking it to differentiate the equation and seeing the steps that it went through. I was hoping for some guidance on where to even start on trying to solve a problem like this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Q:** How did Wolfram Alpha get this integral?

**A** If you change variables $z=e^x$, the indefinite integral you need is
$$\int\frac{1}{z(z-1)^b}\,dz=(1-b)^{-1}(z-1)^{1-b} \, _2F_1(1,1-b;2-b;1-z).$$
This is an integral representation of the hypergeometric function, and Wolfram knows it, see [their site](https://functions.wolfram.com/HypergeometricFunctions/Hypergeometric2F1/07/01/01/). For a derivation of the integral representation, see for example [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/267000586_An_integral_representation_of_some_hypergeometric_functions).